# Crashing when Visual Studio is opened; And Crashing when "New Query" is pressed for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

Two issues in total regarding developing on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.8

I am running Windows Server 2012 (Build 9200)

First Issue:
Visual Studio kept crashing every time I open Visual Studio. So this problem is very persistent. The error is: "TF249053: Team Explorer cannot wrote to the project list configuration file."

I have tried following the instructions in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f0495b1-f84f-4212-84b0-de7d609e4251/tf249053-error?forum=tfsgeneral Like clearing the cache, clearing temp folder, setting the config file to not read only. But they do not work.

So, I decide to reinstall Visual Studio 2015. It still crashes when opening visual studio after reinstallation. But with "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working" error with the following problem details:

```
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 14.0.25420.1
  Problem Signature 03: 57685d85
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.7.3062.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5ab95126
  Problem Signature 07: 3119
  Problem Signature 08: a2
  Problem Signature 09: KUTS43RW3WMPE3EWT1R1Z5M5MTM1NR04
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: dac6
  Additional Information 4: dac6c2650fa14dd558bd9f448e23afd1
```

Second Issue:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio keeps crashing when "New Query" is pressed. "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio has stopped working" error with the following problem details:

```
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: Ssms.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2019.150.18369.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5fd317a3
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.7.3062.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5ab95126
  Problem Signature 07: 3119
  Problem Signature 08: a2
  Problem Signature 09: KUTS43RW3WMPE3EWT1R1Z5M5MTM1NR04
  OS Version:   6.2.9200.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: dac6
  Additional Information 4: dac6c2650fa14dd558bd9f448e23afd1
```

I have referred to this support page for hot fix, but I could not find the "Hotfix download available" section for downloading the hotfix
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/sql-server-management-studio-crashes-when-you-try-to-start-a-new-query-window-in-windows-8-1-e1181a06-3f22-1cf1-f244-adc9373cb363
But the windows version is different, so that the hot fix is not applicable to my case.

It seems that the two issues are related since the Problem Event Name are both CLR20r3 with same Problem Signature for 04: mscorlib?
But I don't know what these problem signature means.
Need help solving these two issues, since currently, I can't get any work done.
Thanks.

Comment: Are they supported on a server OS?

Comment: What version of .NET is installed, is it up to date?

Comment: Version 4.6.1 for .NET. And they are supported on a server OS

Comment: I have update .NET to the latest version, restart the server, but still could not get it to work